# Removing burnt plastic residue from gas cooktop cap

Tags: kitchens, cleaning, stove

Initially, a grimey cooktop:

[image]

After a round of heavy-duty oven cleaner it looks almost brand new:
https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/productdetails/233881

[image]

However... The burnt stain was me getting a plastic bag too close to the burner and it caught fire. I quickly put it out, but some plastic residue remains on the cap.

[image]

How can I get it off?

Comment: These went from silver looking in the first pic to black in the subsequent pics. Is that junk being cleaned off and returning them to their original black, or did you clean them up then paint them black? The Woolworths link (holy cow, they're _still_ in business? I haven't seen one in the US in 30+ years!) is dead, BTW, you may want to update that.

Comment: They are black from the factory. I have a similar (maybe even same model) cooktop. Where you see silver is when OP put the ring on the plain metal area instead of on the burner.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a self-cleaning oven, put the caps on one of the racks the next time you run it. Self-cleaning gets much hotter than a regular oven or cooktop and is much safer than using a torch. I run everything (grates, caps) through in the self-cleaning oven once a year for Passover cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a razor or scraper but with great care.

You can do just enough to get the residue off but it might be easy to damage the surface treatment.

Some of those are actually enamelled and very tough.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with steel wool. It's less likely to result in an oops that damages the cap finish. Work slowly and watch for changes in surface sheen, indicating scratching.

Answer (score 0):

You could heat up the burner and very quickly wipe it off with a lightly soaked rag , be careful for the steam generated to not get burned.